# Add a key value pair to all hashes in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have an Array of hashes.

```
results = [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4}]
```

I want to add an element "c" to all hashes so I end up with:

```
results = [{a:1, b:2, c:"newvalue"},{a:3, b:4, c:"newvalue"}]
```

I'm trying to work a more efficent way of doign this than cycling through the array and doing it one by one.

Should clarify. By "not iterating" I simply mean not writing

```
results.each do |a|
  a[:c] = "newvalue"
end
```

Perhaps the question is a little dumb, but was just thinking there should be something similar to ActiveRecord style

results.update_all(c:"new_value")

which is infinitely more efficent/quicker than iterating through 
... It may be that with an array there's no difference....

or the difference between

```
array.map{|a| [a,2]}
```

and

```
array.product([2])
```

Comment: One way or the other, you must cycle through the array to modify each hash. Do you mean you do not wish to use an iterator directly? If so, why would that be "more efficient"? Just an exercise (which would be OK)?

Comment: "more efficent" why?

Comment: @kris, I was quoting the OP.

Comment: Cary - Sorry, I didn't see your comment, I was asking the same question as you :)

Comment: I cannot think of a way to avoid iterating but here is an extremely convoluted procedure :) `results.product([[[:c,5]]]) {|p| p.first.merge!(p.pop.to_h)}` mostly for @CarySwoveland who loves weird ways to solve problems.

Comment: Just revisiting this as it seems to have had a lot of views. 
THe thinking behind it was the difference between Thing.all.each{|t| t.update_attribute(att:"att")} and Thing.all.update_all(att:"att"). 
the latter is immeasurably quicker. 
I suspect this is a pure DB saving and possibly doesn't help with arrays where everything is held in memory anyway. 
Was just a thought since the syntax also seems a little more friendly.

Comment: Yes, `update_all` is quicker because it is done with one SQL query and does not create any models in memory.

Answer (score 10):

Try this.

```
results.each {|h| h[:c]="newvalue" unless h.include? :c}
```

it will add :c value if not exists.

and if you want to add for all elements without check it.

```
results.each {|h| h[:c]="newvalue"}
```

if you don't to iterate you can ask doing fetch method when you ask for the value.

```
results.fetch(:c, "newvalue")
```

and If you need that value on the hash and you won't to iterate array, you could add default value when you create hashes with (default)

Comment: The OP said nothing about avoiding the replacement of the value of `:c` if `:c` is already a key. The last line was given *verbatem* in an earlier answer that was deleted, presumably because the OP doesn't want to "cycle through the array".

Comment: ok, so you could use fetch method for hash when you use that value. results[0].fetch(:c,"newvalue"). That will return a default value if not exist.

Comment: It might be more descriptive to use `key?` (or `has_key?`) instead of `include?`.

Comment: it's the same I think

Comment: Yes, `include?` is the same as `key?` and `has_key?`.

Comment: Yeah, it is the same, but "key" is more descriptive IMO. Since my first thought on reading is does "include" check the keys or values...

Comment: `has_key?` is deprecated. `key?` is best at conveying meaning. `include?` mostly exists because hashes are `Enumerable`. I would prefer `key?` over `include?`, unless it sounds better in the specific case.

Comment: @ndn, that's an interesting point about `Enumerable#include?`. It seems like it might have made sense (in days of yore) for `Hash#include?` to have take a key-value pair as an argument, or for `Hash` to have just deferred to `Enumerable#include?`, but I'm sure the Ruby monks had a good reason for the decision they took.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, right. For people familiar with the language, it would make slightly more sense if `Hash#include?` was looking for pairs and not keys. But for a person that isn't, it would be a moderately big wtf moment. Ruby exceeds at being intuitive.

Answer (score 7):

Given

```
results = [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4}]
```

Then

```
results.map { |v| v['c'] = 'newvalue'; v }
# => [{:a=>1, :b=>2, "c"=>"newvalue"}, {:a=>3, :b=>4, "c"=>"newvalue"}]
```

When `'newvalue'` isn't static

```
merge_in = ['newvalue1', 'newvalue2']
```

Then

```
results.map.with_index { |hash, i| hash['c'] = merge_in[i]; hash }
# => [{:a=>1, :b=>2, "c"=>"newvalue1"}, {:a=>3, :b=>4, "c"=>"newvalue2"}]
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to "cycle through the array".

Comment: I can't see that being possible :)

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful to me. I had a similar problem to OP and had already attempted to use `map` but had not realized the need to add the `; v` portion at the end. I kept getting only the single hash key value returned instead of the entire hash. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to estimate what will be @Cary Swoveland's critic on my answer, but let me try :)

You have an array of hashes. For my ruby version (1.8.7) I modified it a bit.

```
irb(main):003:0> results = [{'a'=>1, 'b'=>2},{'a'=>3, 'b'=>4}]
```

For adding a new key-value pair to each of these array elements, you have to iterate over them.

In ruby there are lots of ways to do it, but one of them may give you correct understanding on the subject.

```
irb(main):007:0> results.each do |h| # get each element (key-value pairs) of results array  
irb(main):008:1* h['c'] = 'newvalue' #add a new pair to them
irb(main):009:1> end
=> [{"c"=>"newvalue", "b"=>2, "a"=>1}, {"c"=>"newvalue", "b"=>4, "a"=>3}]
# same as results.each {|h| h['c'] ="newvalue"}
```