# Adding more keys to a list of hash conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap

Hello I have a question similar to this ([Add a key value pair to all hashes in an array of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057932/add-a-key-value-pair-to-all-hashes-in-an-array-of-hashes)) but with a bit more complexity

```
def location_records(options)
  materials = [
    {
      name: 'object1'
      area: 'USA'
    },
    {
      name: 'object2'
      area: 'USA'
    }
  ]

  materials.map!{ |material| record_additional_info(material, options) if %w[USA].include?(options.extra_fields_required) }
end

def record_additional_info(materials, options)
  materials[:zip] = 63123
  materials[:state] = 'Missouri'
  materials[:city] = 'Kansas City'
end
```

Say I have this - and I have an array of hash
[{name: 'object1', area: 'USA'}, {name: 'object2', area: 'USA'}]

I want to selective only add additional keys to the hash ONLY if the extra_fields_required is contained in the list of String I provided, say only USA.

So the output of this should be
[{name: 'object1', area: 'USA', zip: 63123, state: 'Missouri', city: 'Kansas City'}, {name: 'object2', area: 'USA', zip: 63123, state: 'Missouri', city: 'Kansas City'}]

But for some reason, I keep getting -

> NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "Kansas City":String

Comment: Do you see the error when you run above code snippet or an extra line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the `material` hash from an invoked method

```
def location_records(options)
  materials = [
    {
      name: 'object1',
      area: 'USA'
    },
    {
      name: 'object2',
      area: 'USA'
    }
  ]

  materials.map!{ |material| record_additional_info(material) if %w[USA].include?(options.extra_fields_required) }

  puts materials     # Prints modified array of hashes
end

def record_additional_info(material)
  material[:zip] = 63123
  material[:state] = 'Missouri'
  material[:city] = 'Kansas City'

  material     # Return the hash object
end
```

Output:

```
{:name=>"object1", :area=>"USA", :zip=>63123, :state=>"Missouri", :city=>"Kansas City"}
{:name=>"object2", :area=>"USA", :zip=>63123, :state=>"Missouri", :city=>"Kansas City"}
```